# How can I avoid a ParserException for required options when user just wants to print usage?

Tags: java, apache-commons-cli

So I have an `Options` instance which among other options has (notice the `isRequired()`):

```java
        options.addOption(OptionBuilder
                .withLongOpt("seq1")
                .withDescription("REQUIRED : blah blah")
                .hasArg().isRequired().create());
        options.addOption(OptionBuilder
                .withLongOpt("seq2")
                .withDescription("REQUIRED : blih blih")
                .hasArg().isRequired().create());
        options.addOption(new Option("?", "help", false,
                "print this message and exit"));
```

When I call `parser.parse(args)` throws an exception if `seq1` and `seq2` are not present - but I want to have it print my message and no exception thrown - how to go about it ? This throws NPE in `line.hasOption("help")`, naturally :

```java
CommandLine line = null;
try {
    CommandLineParser parser = new GnuParser();
    // parse the command line arguments
    line = parser.parse(options, args);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    if (line.hasOption("help")) { //NPE
        usage(0);
    }
    System.err.println("Parsing failed.  Reason: " + e.getMessage());
    usage(1);
}

private static void usage(int exitCode) {
    // automatically generate the help statement
    HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();
    formatter.printHelp("Smith Waterman", OPTIONS, true);
    System.exit(exitCode);
}
```

Comment: when the parser.parse() throws a ParseException, no value is returned. This is how java exceptions work. So you'll probably have to check the original args yourself to see if the 'help' option was passed.

Comment: @GreyB :I know (notice the _naturally_)- I am sure there must be another way - actually I found a workaround but I hope someone more knowledgeable will answer - otherwise I will post my workaround as answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10798771/281545)

```
private static final Options OPTIONS = new Options();
private static final Options HELP_OPTIONS = new Options();
OPTIONS.addOption(OptionBuilder
        .withLongOpt("seq1")
        .withArgName("file1")
        .withDescription(
                "REQUIRED : the file containing sequence 1")
        .hasArg().isRequired().create());
// etc
final Option help = new Option("?", "help", false,
        "print this message and exit");
HELP_OPTIONS.addOption(help);
OPTIONS.addOption(help);
// later
CommandLineParser parser = new GnuParser();
CommandLine line = parser.parse(HELP_OPTIONS, args, true); // true so it
// does not throw on unrecognized options
if (line.hasOption("help")) {
    usage(0); // calls exit
}
line = parser.parse(OPTIONS, args);
```

If anything more elegant comes up I would gladly accept it

Comment: This somehow still  failes when `?` or `--help` is added at the end. `command --seq1 --help` would give me a `MissingArgumentException` I made a small check before parsing now

Comment: @superbly: consider reporting it and post the link from the report back here

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not be useful depending on your usage.  Mine is as follows:

- I have one wrapper program (called 'controller')
- there are many commands (called 'tasks') that the controller can run
- each command has its own set of unique command line argument sets

For example:

```
$ controller startall -rsrc foo -dir bar -where baz
```

The first thing done with the arguments is to determine what the command is.  For that I set up a TaskFactory which looks at the first argument, strips off any leading hyphen, and looks it up to see if it's a known task.  I have a 'help' task, which lets my user do:

```
$ controller -help
```

and

```
$ controller help
```

Each task also has a help option, so the user can do:

```
$ controller startall -help
```

That may not help you, though.  I'll post an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following check before parsing to make sure `-h` or `--help` overrules everything else.

```
// check if help is requested
if (Arrays.asList(args).contains("-h")
        || Arrays.asList(args).contains("--help")) {
    usage(0); // print usage with exit 0
}
// parse options
```

Not the nicest solution but it serves my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Commons CLI doesn't handle inter-option dependencies, as you have discovered.  In your case the `--help` option modifies the requirement for `seq1` and `seq2`.

The only real solution is to make all options non-required, and do the dependency verification yourself after the command-line parse is completed.

Comment: Not true - there is a way but I am not really satisfied - will post it though if no one comes up with something more elegant

Answer (score 0):

Extend your chosen parser to ignore unknown options:

[Can Apache Commons CLI options parser ignore unknown command-line options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049470/can-apache-commons-cli-options-parser-ignore-unknown-command-line-options)

And then parse the arguments twice, once for the `-help` argument and once for the normal arguments.  The first time through you should pass it the "ignore" flag, the second time you shouldn't.

Alternately, parse through the options twice, once looking for `-help` and catching (and ignoring) the `MissingOptionException` and then again with the regular arguments.