# Conditional command line option with Apache commons CLI

Tags: java, apache-commons-cli

I am currently using Apache's common CLI library to parse command line options and I was wondering if there's an easy way for conditional requirements.

For example, in the example below I have two required options `-a` and `-b` as well as an optional `-h`, which should show some description. The way the parser works right now is that it expected to throw a ParserException whenever one of the required options is missing. So far so good. My question is if there is a way to not look for required options when `-h` is specified. Since this it's common that `-h` should only print help and not actually starting my app, I'd like to skip checking other command line options.

```java
import org.apache.commons.cli.*;

public class MyClass {

    ...

    public static void main(String[] parameters)
    {
        Options options = new Options();

        Option opt_a = Option.builder("a")
                .argName("A Option")
                .required(true)
                .longOpt("a-option")
                .desc("First option")
                .build();

        Option opt_b = Option.builder("b")
                .argName("B Option")
                .required(true)
                .longOpt("b-option")
                .desc("Second option")
                .build();

        Option opt_h = Option.builder("h")
                .argName("Help")
                .longOpt("help")
                .desc("Shows this help")
                .build();

        options.addOption(opt_a);
        options.addOption(opt_b);
        options.addOption(opt_h);

        CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();

        try {
            CommandLine cmd = parser.parse(options, args);
            ...
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.err.println("Error parsing command line options");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            usage(options);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public static void usage(Options options) {
        String header = "My application\n\n";
        String footer = "\nPlease report issues at http://github.com/user/repo/issues";

        HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();
        formatter.printHelp("MyApp", header, options, footer, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I found the answer to my problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798208/commons-cli-required-groups So my question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

Looks to me like you could probably use an [OptionGroup](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/cli/OptionGroup.html) which is described as:

> A group of mutually exclusive options.

So you would build one `OptionGroup` with your `-h` and one with all of the other options. Then add both `OptionGroup`s.

---

### Added

Some [research](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10798771/823393) suggests using multiple parse attempts:

```
        Options mainOptions = new Options();

        Option opt_a = Option.builder("a")
                .argName("A Option")
                .required(true)
                .longOpt("a-option")
                .desc("First option")
                .build();

        Option opt_b = Option.builder("b")
                .argName("B Option")
                .required(true)
                .longOpt("b-option")
                .desc("Second option")
                .build();
        mainOptions.addOption(opt_a);
        mainOptions.addOption(opt_b);

        Options helpOptions = new Options();
        Option opt_h = Option.builder("h")
                .argName("Help")
                .longOpt("help")
                .desc("Shows this help")
                .build();
        helpOptions.addOption(opt_h);
        CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
        try {
            CommandLine cmds = parser.parse(helpOptions, args, true);
            // have they specified a help option?
            if (cmds.getOptions().length == 0) {
                // No! Try normal options.
                cmds = parser.parse(mainOptions, args);
            } else {
                // They specified a help option.
            }
            //...
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.err.println("Error parsing command line options");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately all options within one group are mutual independent but I would rather like to have a two mutually independent group of options. I am not sure this is what `OptionGroup` should be used for.

Comment: @FLekschas - [Looks like](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10798771/823393) you need to parse multiple times in that case.

Comment: Look at my comment to my question ;)